# Accessing setting from a model.. container is unavailable

Tags: php, containers, slim

Is there a way to access the container and thus the `$app` array of settings from a Slim Model file? It appears that this is ok for controllers but when I try to access `$this->container` always comes back `null`.

Comment: Why do you need access to the container?  It may be that you need to alter the way you think about the container and not need access to it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. All that is not instantiated by the app itself won't be injected with dependencies/have access to the container.

However, there are ways to solve the problem you are facing.

### Using a parameter in the model constructor

You could simply add a parameter in your constructor that takes the settings array:

```
function __construct(array $settings){...}
```

and then pass it when instantiating from a controller.

Pay attention to the fact that a container is not a service locator (see part 1.3 of the [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/)), so you should not pass the container directly.

### Using a factory that contains the array of settings

You could create a Factory that takes the array of settings as constructor, then store an instance in your container and add it as property of your class, this is an extension to the first answer that will save you time by not having to pass the settings as argument ever time.

```
// The factory
class MyModelFactory{
    private array $settings;
    function __construct(array $settings){
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function makeInstance(): MyModel
    {
        return new MyModel($this->settings);
    }
}

// In the controller
class Controller{
    private MyModelFactory $myModelFactory;

    ...

    // In your route method
    $myModelInstance = $this->myModelFactory->makeInstance();
    ...
}
```

I have not included how to put the Factory inside the container and how to populate the controller class with it since this depends on the way you setup your application, but it's the easy part of the whole process :)